# Node.js connect to MySQL Docker container ECONNREFUSED

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

Before you flag this question as a duplicate, please note that I did read other answers, but it didn't solve my problem.

I have a Docker compose file consisting of two services:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: localhost
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: mysql
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    expose:
      - 3307
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/migrations:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: unless-stopped
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: web/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/web
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      PORT: 3000
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    expose:
      - 3000
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "mysql:3307"]
```

/web/Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.11.1

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

After `docker-compose up --build` the services start up, however the ["wait-for-it.sh"](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) script times out when waiting for mySQL to start (so temporarily I am not using it when testing for DB connectivity, I just wait until the console shows that MySQL is ready for accepting incoming connections)

When MySQL is running from the host machine I can login using Sequel Pro and query the DB and get the sample records from `./mysql/migrations`

[image]
[image]

I can also SSH into the running MySQL container and do the same.

However, my Node.js app yields `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3307` when connecting

MySQL init:

```
import * as mysql from 'promise-mysql'

const config = {
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'mydb',
    port: '3307',
    user: 'mysql',
    password: '1234',
    connectionLimit: 10
}

export let db = mysql.createPool(config);
```

MySQL query:

```
import { db } from '../db/client'

export let get = () => {

return db.query('SELECT * FROM users', [])
    .then((results) => {
        return results

    })
    .catch((e) => {
        return Promise.reject(e)
    })
}
```

Route invoked when hitting url /

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import * as repository from '../repository'
export let router = Router();

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {

    let users;

    try{
        users = await repository.users.get();
    } catch(e){
        // ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3307
    }

    res.render('index', {
        users: users
    });
});
```

It's unlikely to be a race condition because at the same time when Node.js fails I can query using Sequel Pro or SSH into the running Docker container and query. So it's probably a case of Node.js not being able to access to MySQL container?

```
{
    error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3307
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3307,
    fatal: true
}
```

Comment: Try your local ip - e.g. 192.168.0.8

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov This would not work in a production environment since my local host machine would not be around. Docker should link the containers.

Comment: Is there a database server inside the "nodejs" docker ??

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This:

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
    ...
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
```

Means that Docker will map the `3307` port of the host to the `3306` port of the container. So you can access from Sequel to `localhost:3307`.

However, it does not mean that the container is listenting to `3307`; the container is in fact still listening to `3306`. When others containers tries to access the `mysql` DNS, it gets translated to the internal container IP, therefore you must connect to `3306`.

So your node config should look like:

```
const config = {
    host: 'mysql',
    database: 'mydb',
    port: '3306',
    user: 'mysql',
    password: '1234',
    connectionLimit: 10
}
```

And this in your docker-compose.yml:

```
command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "mysql:3306"]
```

Note: `wait-for-it.sh` script comes from: https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

Comment: `command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "mysql:3306"]
` on adding this getting error `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 390: /wait-for-it.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: Please update the contents of the file `wait-for-it.sh` and why it works.

Comment: Refer this website for the wait-for-it.sh content
https://dev.to/hugodias/wait-for-mongodb-to-start-on-docker-3h8b

Comment: @Robert : Why host: 'mysql' ? I assume that should be either container's IP or 'localhost'. Isn't ?

Comment: @GajenDissanayake because OP is using docker-compose and `mysql` is the name of the composed container, so it will resolve to the actual container IP. Note how the question points to host:port `mysql:3307`.