# Not accessible to Docker MySQL container from Node.js Express-GraphQL server container

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker-compose, express-graphql

After successfully running both locally on the localhost,
I tried to dockerize and run them for dev environment using nodemon.

```sh
docker-compose up
```

Both container seems to get launched but get failed connection for some reason.

How can I solve the issue and coonnect them?

part of output on the terminal generated error **"ECONNREFUSED"**

```
...
mysqldb    | 2021-09-05T01:27:00.926720Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
mysqldb    | 2021-09-05T01:27:01.230729Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysqldb    | 2021-09-05T01:27:01.757576Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
mysqldb    | 2021-09-05T01:27:01.757980Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
mysqldb    | 2021-09-05T01:27:01.761528Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysqldb    | 2021-09-05T01:27:01.761974Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
mysqldb    | 2021-09-05T01:27:01.767829Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysqldb    | 2021-09-05T01:27:01.848770Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.26'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
mysqldb    | 2021-09-05T01:27:01.849567Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
mysqldb    | 2021-09-05 01:27:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
simple-crud-server-ctn | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.2:3306
simple-crud-server-ctn |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1148:16) {
simple-crud-server-ctn |   errno: -111,
simple-crud-server-ctn |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
simple-crud-server-ctn |   syscall: 'connect',
simple-crud-server-ctn |   address: '172.19.0.2',
simple-crud-server-ctn |   port: 3306,
simple-crud-server-ctn |   fatal: true
simple-crud-server-ctn | }
simple-crud-server-ctn | [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
mysqldb    | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysqldb    | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysqldb    | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysqldb    | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysqldb    | 2021-09-05 01:27:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database test
mysqldb    | 2021-09-05 01:27:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user ernest
mysqldb    | 2021-09-05 01:27:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user ernest access to schema test
mysqldb    | 
mysqldb    | 2021-09-05 01:27:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    image: simple-crud-server
    container_name: simple-crud-server-ctn
    restart: always
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: 'mysqldb'
      DATABASE_USER: 'ernest'
      DATABASE_PASS: 'root'
      DATABASE_NAME: 'test'

    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: yarn dev:docker
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
    networks:
      - simple-crud-app
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
mysqldb:
    container_name: mysqldb
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root' 
      MYSQL_USER: 'ernest'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'      
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test'    
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./mysqlData:/data/db
    networks:
      - simple-crud-app
volumes:
  mysqlData:
networks:
  simple-crud-app:
    driver: bridge
```

**index.js in server**

```
import express from "express";
import { graphqlHTTP } from "express-graphql";
import { schema } from "./Schema";
import cors from "cors";
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";
import { Users } from "./Entities/Users";

const main = async () => {

    await createConnection({
        type: "mysql",
        host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
        database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
        username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
        password: process.env.DATABASE_PASS,
        logging: true,
        synchronize: false,
        entities: [Users]
    });

    const app = express();
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use("/graphql", graphqlHTTP({
        schema,
        graphiql: true
    }));

    app.listen(4000, () => {
        console.log("Server is running now on PORT 4000");
    });
};
```

**Dockerfile for server**

```
## Install packages without output on the terminal
RUN yarn install --silent

# Copy app source code
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# show all files and directories when building image
RUN echo "Current directory in Docker is ${PWD}" && ls -a

# port number
EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["yarn", "dev:docker"]
```

Comment: Are you sure you have bind the ip?

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta Does that mean specifying PORTS 3306:3306  and specifying database host? if wrong, I want you tell me what binding IP mean. Thank you.

Comment: please look https://stackoverflow.com/a/45400106/713789